# AJAX Reload Misbehaving with Marquee

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reload, marquee

I'm working on getting a [marquee](https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee) to reload after each run.  It's working fine, until it reloads.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.1/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .subclass1 { white-space: nowrap; height: 55px; display: inline-block; padding: 5 10 5 5; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>No Reload</h1>
        
        <div class="ticker-main-box scroller1" data-duplicated="true" style="border: 1px #000 solid;">
                <?php echo file_get_contents("simpleData.txt"); ?>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 50px"></div>
        <h1>Supposed to Reload</h1>
        <div class="ticker-main-box scroller2" style="border: 1px #000 solid;">
                <?php echo file_get_contents("simpleData.txt"); ?>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            console.log("Load Marquee...");
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                
                var tickerSettings = (
                        {direction: 'left'},
                        {speed: 40},
                        {duration: 10000});

                $('.scroller2')
                    .bind('finished', function(){
                        //First, "destroy" the marquee so it's ready for new content
                        $(this).marquee('destroy');
                        //Second, Load new content using Ajax and update the marquee container
                        $(this).html($(this).load('simpleData.txt'))
                            //Reapply the Marquee
                            .marquee(tickerSettings)
                    })
                    .marquee(tickerSettings);
                    
                $('.scroller1').marquee(tickerSettings);

            });
            console.log("Loaded Marquee...");
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
?>
```

The contents of the test file (`simpleData.txt`) look like this:

```
<div class="subclass1">1.  Text that gets rotated</div>
<div class="subclass1">2.  Text that gets rotated</div>
<div class="subclass1">3.  Text that gets rotated</div>
<div class="subclass1">4.  Text that gets rotated</div>
```

The **No Reload** endlessly scrolls (as expected).  The **Supposed to Reload** section scrolls once then stops.  I've followed the pattern [here](https://codepen.io/aamirafridi/pen/ayBmF), but can't get it to behave as expected. Once it reloads, the text stops scrolling and is all displayed all at once in the container.

EDIT:

I know there are better ways to load the file.  Loading the file isn't the problem.  I get the same results when I do something like this:

```
$.ajax({url: "simpleData.txt", success: function(tickerData){
                    $(".scroller2").html(tickerData);
                }, error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log(xhr.status);
                    console.log(thrownError);
                }})
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

hello I had the same problem, solutions add it in the ajax in the always (you can still do it after `$(".scroller2").html(tickerData);`)

the next line

```
$('.here your class').marquee();
```